# FFMpeg dropping frames at end of file using image2 demux with multiple encoders, any solutions?

Tags: ffmpeg

Alright, real simple here. I'm rendering some fractal flames I've created over the years. Which makes the math on all of this really simple.. lol.

I'm trying to generate a 5 second video at 60fps that when played continuously makes a perfect loop.

So I sequence and render exactly 300 frames numbered 000.png through 299.png for one loop. I then send this into FFMpeg with the following command:

> ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 60 -start_number 0 -i '%03d.png' -r 60
> -crf 10 output.webm

No matter what, it kills the last 12-18 frames depending on the run and creates a video that players recognize as 4 seconds only.

Here is a snippet of the processing output (Take note that 300 frames at 60fps no matter what you do comes out at 04.66 seconds - but it does claim there are exactly 5 seconds on the input side)

[image]

I have tried replacing -crf setting with just -quality good, I have tried moving around where I state the framerate. I have tried removing the -r from the output and putting it in there. I have tried building out this call to be as specific as possible such as the strictly specifying the encoder and options. Oh I have tried other encoders and get the same result. I have even tried -hwaccell using NVEC and CUVID respectively.

Nothing I do works..

Any thoughts here? Maybe alternatives to FFMpeg? Maybe difference versions of FFMpeg? I don't know what I should do next and thought I would ask.

Diagnostic output on a finished file for reference this one actually got close with 294 frames and a 4.9 second runtime it is much higher res though:

[image]

Comment: What's the output of `ffmpeg -i output.webm`?

Comment: @Lex let me update my question to post another photo

Comment: @Lex that's been included now

Comment: What will happen if you loop the input series of images a few times? You can try to use `-stream_loop` option to do that. Will you still see that some frames are missing at the end the first pass?

Comment: Actually no, if I loop 2 or more times from the raw png sources it does actually grab all of the frames for every loop except for the last loop where it drops the frames again.

Comment: One other thing to note that this scales and becomes worse the more frames I decide to do. I've tried all the way upto 1800 frames in 300 frame intervals to create a single loop. Effectively slowing down the animation across more time. The average frame loss at the end of the file is about 3.2%

This is verified with ffprobe grabbing the frame count of finished output

Comment: These "missing frames" could be the problem of your player not FFmpeg. For example: I'm using VLC and it often does not play "a few last seconds" of any video. To see all your important frames every time in any player you can some add additional black frames at the end of the video.

Comment: I'm not sure it is unfortunately, considering that ffprobe verifies there are not 300 frames in a 300 frame requested encoding.